# Facebook In App Browser causing issues on WordPress website

Tags: css, wordpress, facebook

I have built a website on WordPress using the Kadence WP Theme URL here for the site below.

https://brickstoriches.co.uk/earlybird/

Works well on other browsers except for Facebooks in the app browser as the site uses Facebook Ads, so this is a crucial part of the site.

https://www.facebook.com/business/help/206578174518231

The issue I'm facing on IOS devices and when the website is viewed from the Facebook browser the site appears to have CSS issues.

See picture below

[Image of the website in the Facebook browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vkzr1.jpg)

Anyone have a solution to this issue or a way to debug from the Facebook in-app browser?

Thank you in advance.

I have tried many different methods of debugging this issue. Such as putting my phone on developer mode with USB debugging enabled and then using viewing the Facebook in app browser page from my desktop. This didn't seem to work.